# c++ data structures heaps

Tags: c++, oop, heap, binary-tree

I've been trying to implement a heap into my program. It seems to me that heaps are the same as binary trees. Is this the case with all heaps such as min heap and max heap since all that is being done is a traversal through the tree putting the largest/smallest node to the top?

Also, I've read that using 1-D arrays are only beneficial when we have a complete binary tree. If we don't have a complete binary tree, it would be more beneficial to use class that is a friend class to another? Why is that? Such as:

```
template<class T> class BT; // forward declartion -> added at edit

template<class T>
class BTNode{
    friend class BT<T>; // not sure why we need two classes
private:
    T data;
    BTNode<T> *leftChild; // what is the benefit of making a object Node?
    BTNode<T> *rightChild;
};

template<class T>
class BT{
private:
    BTNode<T> *root; // what is the benefit of having this root in another class?
};
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This is what is used in containers such as `std::priority_queue`, and is called a **heap**.

Comment: @Aesthete: nit-picking, I know. A `heap` is a concrete data-structure; a `priority queue` is an abstract datatype (i.e., an interface) which can be implemented with a heap, but also in other ways. `std::priority_queue` is a container adaptor, not a container.

Comment: It's the default implementation, and the semantic nitpicking completely detracts from the point I was trying to make, which was for a previous comment that has already been removed.

Comment: And I was talking explicity about `std::priority_queue`, not the concept of one, which requires the internal container to support random access iterators so that `make_heap`, `push_heap` and `pop_heap` can be called on it.

Answer (score 1):

There's a perfectly good heap implementation in the standard library; you should take a look at it (but it is a useful learning exercise to write your own, too.)

A binary heap is a binary tree, but it is stored efficiently as a vector. The links are implicit. That is to say, the children of the node at position `i` (zero-based) are at `2i+1` and `2i+2`. (At most one node in a heap has only one child.)  That means that you don't actually have to store links, so in the case of small data objects (like integers), you're saving at least two-thirds of the needed space.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap) has a nice article on binary heaps (the kind you normally store in vectors), but it also has a number of articles on other types of [heaps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_%28data_structure%29).

Comment: Yep, `std::make_heap(beg, end);` where beg and end are  `std::vector::iterator` types.

Comment: I'll look into the the STL library. That seems like a good place to start since I have to implement a min heap w/o the STL library.